# Facebook Icon on top of Wordpress Site Header and Top Bar

Tags: themes

I did some changes on my website and there seems to be a problem. While everything in the new theme is working, I found out that there is an annoying facebook icon, located on top of my header and top bar.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I would like to know why there's a facebook icon there and how can I remove it? I am using a Basic Wordpress deal, so know that I can not actually go to the code and remove it.

Thank you!

Comment: What's a basic WordPress deal? Which host are you using?

Comment: But I'd guess how to remove it is going to depend on 1) where it's coming from, which you can try and track down with your web browser's inspect tools and ideally with the source code to the themes and plugins you're using even if you can't modify them, 2) what access you do have to change things - is it just the WordPress admin site? You may have to ask your host for help.

Comment: Where does the Facebook icon link to? Your page, or your host's page, or something else?

Comment: And was the icon there before you made the changes? What changes did you make?

Comment: Hello Rup, I will answer all your questions in one go. - Basic hosting deal means wordpress takes care of the hosting and puts it on GoDaddy.

Yeah I did see it and it goes to a fa facebook icon somewhere else and it leads to nothing. It just shows that one annoying line of small icon.

The icon wasn't there before the changes. I just changed the theme from an import function in Wordpress Themes.

Comment: OK, it sounds like a bug in a plugin or the theme then. You should ask your host to fix this, since it's a bug in the software and they completely control the software. As far as I can see wordpress.com and wordpress.org don't manage hosting plans on GoDaddy, though, so I'd guess it's actually GoDaddy that you're paying for this, so it's them you need to talk to. (Either way, talk to whoever you're actually paying.)